# how to define UIFont as constant value in swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uifont

I want to define a UIFont as constant value in swift so i can reuse it app to make it consistent. I have used this in Objective-C by `#define HelveticaNeue [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:13.0]` I want this code in swift. How can i get this.

I have Used let to define constant in swift and it works on string but not working on UIFont or any other object.

I have also tried other keywords like static, extern,var etc with no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
struct FontHelper {
static func defaultRegularFontWithSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Regular", size: size)!
}

static func defaultLightFontWithSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Light", size: size)!
}

static func defaultSemiBoldFontWithSize(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: "SourceSansPro-Semibold", size: size)!
}}
```

To use it: `let font = FontHelper.defaultRegularFontWithSize(15)`.

Answer (score 7):

`#define` does not exist in Swift, but essentially all it does is replace every instance of that constant name with that text before it compiles which isn't very efficient. Instead use `let header = UIFont(name: "someFont", size: 20.0)!` to define a constant in Swift. I would try to avoid defining global constants, but the scope of how you use that is up to you. Personally, I use a Font struct with static constants to store all of my fonts:

```
// MARK: Font Struct
struct Font {
    static let header = UIFont(name: "agbookrounded-medium", size: 20.0)!
    static let subheader = UIFont(name: "AvenirLTStd-Black", size: 16.0)!
    static let body1 = UIFont(name: "AvenirLTStd-Roman", size: 14.0)!
    static let body2 = UIFont(name: "AvenirLTStd-Light", size: 10.0)!
}
```

and you access an individual font using:

```
Font.header
```

and to alter the size:

```
Font.header.fontWithSize(32.0)
```